# Problem Deploying Report Parts into SharePoint 2010 Integrated SSRS 2008 R2 Instance

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have deployed an SSRS 2008 R2 project into our SharePoint Integration.  This worked no problem.  I then wanted to add report parts.  I converted the DataSource and DataSets to Shared Components and re-deployed.  No problem.  I then selected the parts that I wanted to publish.  Now when I deploy the project I get the error message:

Warning : Referenced item ReportsTo doesn't exist at http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Datasets/ReportsTo.rsds.

The item ReportsTo is a part that is trying to get published.  This has me a little confused.  I was under the impression that the rsds file type is soley for DataSources.  Given that the path that is in the error is Datasets should it not be looking for a DataSet file?

Any help in resolving this to get the parts published would be greatly appreciated.

I am working in BIDS 2008 R2 not Report Builder

**UPDATE:..** After Reviewing the Logs on the Reporting Server I noticed this.

GetPropertiesAction(http://dev-sp01/sites/ThriveReporting/http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Report Parts/TeamUtilizationOverWeeks_Chart.rsc, PathBased).

It looks like it is trying to merge the Site name with the Fully Qualified Path to the Reports Parts.  In BIDS I've tried to change the Report Parts path in the deployment properties to the relative path to the Site Name provided, but it errors out and requests the Fully Qualified path. It would seem that this might be a bug.

So to Recap

When trying to Publish Report Parts

1) Bids Gives me the Warning:

Warning : Referenced item ReportsTo doesn't exist at 'http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Datasets/ReportsTo.rsds.'

Where ReportsTo is a Shared Dataset, so I beleive this should be looking for an rsd extention.  In the Log there is a corresponding action for this but not error

Warning : Referenced item ReportsTo doesn't exist at 'http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Datasets/ReportsTo.rsds.'

GetItemTypeAction(http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Datasets/ReportsTo.rsds).

2) Reporting Services does not appear to be creating a path correctly to access a Report Part during deployment.

GetPropertiesAction(http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/http://dev-sp01/sites/CompanyName/Shared Documents/Reporting/Report Parts/TeamUtilizationOverWeeks_Chart.rsc, PathBased).

Comment: Response from MS -  "Thanks for bringing this bug to our attention.
The bug has been fixed for the next release for SQL Server and the fix would be ported over in the next PCU update of SQL Server 2008 R2 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft, I am submitting Feedback now.

Hi Matt,

I can reproduce the issue. It seems to be a known issue. 
I would suggest you submitting a feedback at https://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver. 
Your feedback enables Microsoft to make software and services the best that they can be, and you can learn about and contribute to exciting projects.

Thanks,
Jin Chen

---

Jin Chen - MSFT

**UPDATE:**

Please go to [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/635104/ssrs-2008-r2-not-working-properly-with-sharepoint-2010) and vote this issue as important so that it will get looked at sooner.